# Apply shadow to the navigation bar in swift

Tags: ios, swift

In my design navigation of app have nice shadow and i want to apply in my code.
How to i can create this effect?

[image]

Answer (score 50):

without adding the view

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.masksToBounds = false
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2.0)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowRadius = 2
```

Comment: I try this code and other code also but problem is when i use this navigation become light gray color. But i want navigation with white color and button shadow.

Comment: I had to add this in `viewWillAppear`, otherwise I wouldn't see the shadow.

Comment: be aware that your navigationController is shared within controllers, if u want the shadow to be in all controllers its maybe best to setup shadow in appdelegate

Comment: @Faruk Duric, worked like a M@gic Swift 4.1 . Thanks!!

Comment: This should be accepted answer. Works for Swift 4.2!

Answer (score 5):

I've done this before by adding a view underneath the navigation bar.

```
func addShadowToBar() {
    let shadowView = UIView(frame: self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame)
    shadowView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    shadowView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    shadowView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.4 // your opacity
    shadowView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2) // your offset
    shadowView.layer.shadowRadius =  4 //your radius
    self.view.addSubview(shadowView)
}
```

Comment: This code not works, please edit your answer or delete it

Answer (score 3):

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 2.0)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.masksToBounds = false
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if I am not wrong, the defaults navigation bar already comes with a shadow. But if you're making a custom one with a UIView then you should do this to make your life easier

```
yourView.clipsToBounds = false
yourView.layer.shadowOffset.height = 5 //this is your offset
yourView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.25 //opacity of your shadow (recommended)
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3:

```
let shadowView = UIView(frame: navBar.frame)
shadowView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
shadowView.layer.masksToBounds = false
shadowView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
shadowView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
shadowView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2.0)
shadowView.layer.shadowRadius = 2
view.addSubview(shadowView)
```